Why are the stems of my grass so much taller than the leaves?
I'm not sure if I am misunderstanding what I'm seeing here, but it looks like my grass is mostly stems growing really tall and the leaves of the grass laying out down towards the ground.

I just moved into this house, so I'm not sure what has been done to this yard previously, and I haven't even been able to identify the type of grass we have. I am in a colder climate, and I read that colder climate grasses should be kept longer, so I have been mowing at about 3.5". This picture was taken before mowing, so it's probably 4-4.5".
The grass stems are very uncomfortable to walk on, so I'm wondering what I can do to fix whatever is going on here.

Looks like it was let go to grow very tall (like 10-12" tall) earlier this spring. So it resembles "hayfield stubble" more than "lawn grass" (which is not a matter of species, it's an effect of letting it get out of hand too tall.)
Not unusual for an unoccupied house with "other things" on the owner's agenda. Mow it at 3.5" for a month more and see if it becomes more reasonable.
Or even whack it down to 2" or less, just once, as a correction, and then mow at 3.5"

That's true! It was left to grow for over a month before we moved in
